# How to prolong a spell in absence?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic

In Pathfinder lets say that I am a medium to high level wizard and I cast "[Charm Monster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/Charme-monster)" on someone on whom I want to have control over. This spell lasts a couple days. (Side question: does the person get a will save each day?)

Now, I don't want to stay close to this person, and I might travel away for a couple of weeks. How can I prolong the spell if I am not in the vicinity of the person? I want to have the person to stay charmed as long as possible.

To clarify the need for the spell to last: the charmed person is intelligent, and normally not inclined to obey my will. He was an enemy before, and my intention is to abase him. (Yes, somewhat evil and self-righteous, I know.)

I want him to e.g. protect my treasure until I return. If the spell stops, the person would take my money and run. So I need him to stay under my spell.

I think, a couple of weeks should be enough, so I'll use extended spell and make sure that I'll return on time. In an extreme case with a teleport spell/scroll.

Comment: From the "Charm Monster" page: "This spell functions like charm person", which has one will save, but doesn't last so long.

Comment: Related question to how Charm actually functions: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/12060/1736

Comment: You might get more useful answers if you asked about your specific problem, rather than your solution.  It sounds like your problem is that you need someone loyal to guard your stuff for an arbitrary period of time, not that you specifically need Charm Monster to do it.  If we came up with a way for a loyal ally to guard your stuff for a while that didn't use Charm Monster, would that be an acceptable answer?  If so, you might want to alter your question.

Comment: If you really do need Charm Monster specifically, could you tell us what level you are, what kind of resources you're willing to spend, and how long, exactly, you need the spell to last?  If you're going to come back every 3 weeks guaranteed, then it's an easier problem than if we have to account for several month long absences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it's unlikely that you're going to be able to keep someone charmed indefinitely with Charm Monster.  It's likely that there's some higher-level jiggery-pokery that can do it, but I'm not aware of a simple way to make charms last more than a few weeks.  Here are some alternates:

**Extend Spell**

The simple, but not great, solution.  This makes the spell last twice as long as normal, giving you a few extra days of breathing room.  At level 10, an Extended Charm Monster lasts for about 3 weeks.  At level 20 it'll last almost a month and a half.  If you don't have the feat, you can buy a [Rod of Extend Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/metamagic-rods/metamagic-extend) for 11,000 gp that will work with Charm Monster.

**Pay the guy.**

This depends a lot on exactly how powerful a person you want to charm.  A trained [hireling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/hirelings-servants-services) costs about 1 sp per day, and would likely be a low-level [Warrior](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/npc-classes/warrior).  If the person is higher level, it gets a bit more expensive.You could probably higher someone around level 5 for something like 25 gp per day, depending on how secure you want your stuff to be.  The rubric I usually use for hiring higher-level NPCs is to charge 1% of their [starting wealth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement) per day.  Since a 5th level basic NPC has 2,400 gp, 25 gp per day sounds reasonable to me.  You would definitely have to work this out with your GM.

However, once you have them charmed, you can likely haggle for a much better price.  I'd offer a 10-25% discount, depending on an opposed Diplomacy check.  While they wouldn't accept such a low price if they weren't charmed, personal honor will keep them guarding your stuff until you come back.  It's hard to get work if people know that you abandoned a contract before it was up.

**Take the Leadership feat**

This takes quite a bit more resources than the above, but is still possible.  If you take [Leadership](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/leadership---final), you can probably take your new friend as your cohort, or a follower if they're low enough level.  It's a totally legit use of the feat to have your followers protect your treasure while you're out adventuring.

**Actually befriend him.**

Once you have him charmed, and he is trusting you magically, spend some time to actually befriend the guy.  This is time-consuming and might require some intense roleplaying, but if it works, you have someone who actually wants to help you of their own accord, rather than someone who you are magically bending to your will.  With this approach, you're just using the charm spell to get your foot in the door, so to speak, to make it easier to get your target to genuinely trust you.  This will definitely require GM aid, as well as approval.

Answer (score 3):

So Charm Monster is a 3rd+ level spell, so the charm is at least 5 days for any of the classes that can cast it.

Here's the thing about the Charm spells, there is a lot of DM fiat in how this actually plays out.

- How are you actually treating the Monster under the charm?
- How long has this charming been happening prior to your departure.
- What is the alignment of the Monster? True Neutral? Chaotic Evil? Are they strongly aligned like a Devil / Anti-paladin or weakly aligned like a normal peasant.
- What is the Intelligence and Wisdom of the Monster? Does the Monster understand that it was magically manipulated?
- Do you have other skills for "handling" the Monster? (*Handle Animal / Diplomacy / Intimidation*)

**Why do all of these matter?**

The Charm spell converts this Monster into your *Friendly* (*as per the [Diplomacy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/diplomacy) rules on Attitude*), but that doesn't mean that they revert to their previous Attitude when done.

Think of it this way. Imagine that you (*the target*), meet me in a dark alley and your immediate reaction is *Unfriendly*. But then you get Charmed by my Wizard and convert over to *Friendly*. Me and my party offer to take you for a great meal at your favourite restaurant and then drive you home in our limo. You are our Friend and agree to this whole thing.

**A few hours later, the Charm wears off, so how do you feel about me and the party now?** Well, we didn't do anything bad to you and you earnestly had a good time (*charmed or not*). Well you're probably going to treat us like a *Friend* on our next encounter unless you have some real overwhelming reason to think that we're screwing you over.

That's why you have to refer to the bullet points above. If there's no really good reason for the Monster to "hate you" after the Charm wears off, you may not need to Charm it ever again.

Comment: I added a clarificazion why the spell should last. A new friendship is not enough security in my case.